# Async implementation of IValueConverter

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, c#-5.0, winrt-async

I have an asynchronous method which I want to trigger inside an `IValueConverter`.

Is there a better way than forcing it to be synchronous by calling the `Result` property?

```
public async Task<object> Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    StorageFile file = value as StorageFile;

    if (file != null)
    {
        var image = ImageEx.ImageFromFile(file).Result;
        return image;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("invalid parameter");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You probably don't want to call `Task.Result`, for a couple of reasons.

Firstly, as I explain in detail on my blog, [you can deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) unless your `async` code is has been written using `ConfigureAwait` everywhere. Secondly, you probably don't want to (synchronously) block your UI; it would be better to temporarily show a "loading..." or blank image while reading from the disk, and update when the read completes.

So, personally, I would make this part of my ViewModel, not a value converter. I have a blog post describing some [databinding-friendly ways to do asynchronous initialization](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html). That would be my first choice. It just doesn't feel right to have a *value converter* kicking off asynchronous background operations.

However, if you've considered your design and really think an asynchronous value converter is what you need, then you have to get a bit inventive. The problem with value converters is that they *have* to be synchronous: the data binding starts at the data context, evaluates the path, and then invokes a value conversion. Only the data context and path support change notifications.

So, you have to use a (synchronous) value converter in your data context to convert your original value into a databinding-friendly `Task`-like object and then your property binding just uses one of the properties on the `Task`-like object to get the result.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<TextBox Text="" Name="Input"/>
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Input, Path=Text, Converter={local:MyAsyncValueConverter}}"
           Text="{Binding Path=Result}"/>
```

The `TextBox` is just an input box. The `TextBlock` first sets its own `DataContext` to the `TextBox`'s input text running it through an "asynchronous" converter. `TextBlock.Text` is set to the `Result` of that converter.

The converter is pretty simple:

```
public class MyAsyncValueConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = (string)value;
        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            return val + " done!";
        });
        return new TaskCompletionNotifier<string>(task);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

The converter first starts an asynchronous operation to wait 5 seconds and then add " done!" to the end of the input string. The result of the converter can't be just a plain `Task` because `Task` doesn't implement `IPropertyNotifyChanged`, so I'm using a type that will be in the next release of my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com). It looks something like this (simplified for this example; [full source is available](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/7776f08613e7#Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20%28NET4,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75%29/TaskCompletionNotifier%20%28of%20TResult%29.cs)):

```
// Watches a task and raises property-changed notifications when the task completes.
public sealed class TaskCompletionNotifier<TResult> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TaskCompletionNotifier(Task<TResult> task)
    {
        Task = task;
        if (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            var scheduler = (SynchronizationContext.Current == null) ? TaskScheduler.Current : TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
                if (propertyChanged != null)
                {
                    propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsCompleted"));
                    if (t.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsCanceled"));
                    }
                    else if (t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsFaulted"));
                        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ErrorMessage"));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSuccessfullyCompleted"));
                        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Result"));
                    }
                }
            },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
            scheduler);
        }
    }

    // Gets the task being watched. This property never changes and is never <c>null</c>.
    public Task<TResult> Task { get; private set; }

    Task ITaskCompletionNotifier.Task
    {
        get { return Task; }
    }

    // Gets the result of the task. Returns the default value of TResult if the task has not completed successfully.
    public TResult Result { get { return (Task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) ? Task.Result : default(TResult); } }

    // Gets whether the task has completed.
    public bool IsCompleted { get { return Task.IsCompleted; } }

    // Gets whether the task has completed successfully.
    public bool IsSuccessfullyCompleted { get { return Task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion; } }

    // Gets whether the task has been canceled.
    public bool IsCanceled { get { return Task.IsCanceled; } }

    // Gets whether the task has faulted.
    public bool IsFaulted { get { return Task.IsFaulted; } }

    // Gets the error message for the original faulting exception for the task. Returns <c>null</c> if the task is not faulted.
    public string ErrorMessage { get { return (InnerException == null) ? null : InnerException.Message; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

By putting these pieces together, we've created an asynchronous data context that is the result of a value converter. The databinding-friendly `Task` wrapper will just use the default result (usually `null` or `0`) until the `Task` completes. So the wrapper's `Result` is quite different than `Task.Result`: it won't synchronously block and there's no danger of deadlock.

But to reiterate: I'd choose to put asynchronous logic into the ViewModel rather than a value converter.

Comment: Hi Thanks for yoru reply. Making the async operation in viewmodel is indeed the solution i currently have as a workaround. but this feel very nice. There are some concerns for which I feel they were right in a converter. I hoped that I overlooked something like a IAsyncValueConverter. But it seems like there is nothing like that :-( .

Will mark your post although as an answer because I think it will help some other guys with same problems :-)

Comment: Very nice, but I want to ask you a question: why the converter should extend `MarkupExtension` and why `ProvideValue` returns itself?

Comment: @Alberto: It's just a XAML convenience so you don't have to declare a global instance in a resource dictionary and reference it from your markup.

Comment: @StephenCleary, what is the purpose of the explicit implementation of ```ITaskCompletionNotifier```? I don't see the definition in your answer anywhere.

Comment: The code in my answer is a simplification of the code linked to in my answer. The explicit implementation is because I have a generic `ITaskCompletionNotifier<T>` that derives from `ITaskCompletionNotifier`. See my [MSDN article on async data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) for a more complete example.

Comment: Is this applicable in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: @mr5: I don't know. [This kind of data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) is applicable to any MVVM framework, including Xamarin; but the `MarkupConverter` / `IValueConverter` wrapper is pretty WPF-specific and would only work on Xamarin if they have similar types.

Comment: Codeplex shuts down. The source code linked in the answer can now be found under https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx

Answer (score 1):

The alternative approach is to make your own control which supports async sources or data.

Here is the example with the image

```
    public class AsyncSourceCachedImage : CachedImage
{
    public static BindableProperty AsyncSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AsyncSource), typeof(Task<Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource>), typeof(AsyncSourceSvgCachedImage), null, propertyChanged: SourceAsyncPropertyChanged);

    public Task<Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource> AsyncSource
    {
        get { return (Task<Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource>)GetValue(AsyncSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AsyncSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    private static async void SourceAsyncPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldColor, object newColor)
    {
        var view = bindable as AsyncSourceCachedImage;
        var taskForImageSource = newColor as Task<Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource>;

        if (taskForImageSource != null)
        {
            var awaitedImageSource = await taskForImageSource;

            view.Source = awaitedImageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, you might implement the loading activity indicator over the image until the task will be resolved.