# WPF's Imagecontrol freezes the UI

Tags: c#, wpf, image, servicepointmanager

I want to display a Users Gravatar in my WPF-Application. This is how I bind the Image-Control:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Email, Converter={StaticResource GravatarConverter},IsAsync=True}">
```

Where GravatarConverter returns the URL for the given Email. Unfortunately this is blocking my UI completely when loading the first Image. Please note that I am using "IsAsync=True". 
After some research I found out that I can hack around this issue when calling FindServicePoint in a separate thread on applications startup:

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew( () => ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint( "http://www.gravatar.com", WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy ) );
```

But this is not working when FindServicePoint isn't finished while my Application is already downloading an image.
Can someone please explain why a WPF-App needs this FindServicePoint at all, why this is blocking the UI and how to avoid the blocking?

Thanks

**Update**: As it turns out my problem disappeared after I unchecked "Automatic detect settings" in Internet Explorers "Internet Options"->"Connections"->"LAN Settings".

I used this VERY simple WPF-Application to reproduce the problem just by inserting an url for an image in the textbox and click the button. With "Automatic detect settings" enabled the app freezes for some seconds the first time an image gets loaded. With this option disabled its loading immediately.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfGravatarFreezeTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="tbEmail" />
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Click="buttonLoad_OnClick" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Set Source</Button>
    <Image x:Name="img" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfGravatarFreezeTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonLoad_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            try { this.img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.tbEmail.Text)); }
            catch( Exception ){}            
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking UI happans because **IsAsync=True** runs in async manner only binding process. In your case you have a long running operation during converting process. To solve this you should create converter that presents the result asynchronously like this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003827/async-implementation-of-ivalueconverter)):

**Create task complition notifier:**

```
public sealed class TaskCompletionNotifier<TResult> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TaskCompletionNotifier(Task<TResult> task)
    {
        Task = task;
        if (task.IsCompleted) return;
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var temp = PropertyChanged;
            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Result"));
            }
        }); 
    }

    // Gets the task being watched. This property never changes and is never <c>null</c>.
    public Task<TResult> Task { get; private set; }

    // Gets the result of the task. Returns the default value of TResult if the task has not completed successfully.
    public TResult Result { get { return (Task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) ? Task.Result : default(TResult); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

**Create async converter implementing MarkupExtention:**

```
public class ImageConverter: MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{

    public ImageConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return new BitmapImage();
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // Perform your long running operation and request here
            return value.ToString();
        });

        return new TaskCompletionNotifier<string>(task);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

}
```

**Use it in Xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox x:Name="uri" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ImageUri, ElementName=main}"/>
    <Image Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding Text, ElementName=uri, Converter={local:ImageConverter}}" Source="{Binding Path=Result, IsAsync=True}"/>

</Grid>
```

**Update 2**
Seems like **Image** control load images asynchronously itself. You are right first load take a lot of time. You may use code like this:

```
    try
    {
        var uri = Uri.Text;
        var client = new WebClient();
        var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(uri);
        var source = new BitmapImage();
        source.BeginInit();
        source.StreamSource = stream;
        source.EndInit();
        Img.Source = source;


    }
    catch (Exception) { }
```

But its performance is't better than your variant.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. Unfortunately this is still freezing my up UI. It looks like it doesn't matter if I execute this asynchronously - the problem seems to be this ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint call which is executed once per app the first time a remote image is downloaded.

Comment: In my case all works without freezing. Where do you call ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint? Can you provide some code? Also pay attantion that I set IsAsync=True.

Comment: Okay I found the "bug" - but this is really strange: it has to do with internet settings in Internet Explorer. I had "Automatic detect settings" in "Settings"->"Connections"->"Lan Settings" activated. When I deactivate it everything loads perfect, when I activate it it freezes. So this seems to be a OS-Problem?

Comment: That's realy strange. I don't think that problem in OS. Do you execute ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint method in a Task.Run as I show in example? If you provide your problematic code It's increase chance that I help you.