# WP8.1 C# Binding Contact Image

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1, contacts

**Information**
Quite simply, I’m attempting to create an app that would display the contacts for a user.

I’m also a self-taught programmer, so I have experience with programming in some aspects, but I am relatively new to data-binding in general.

To begin, I have a ListView control that has an image binding within it.

```
<ListView x:Name="ContactsView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="ContactImage" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ContactPictureConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I also have a converter that gets an IRandomAccessStream of the Contact Image and returns it as a BitmapImage. If no image is found (null exception), then the converter will return back a default picture for contacts.

```
public class ContactPictureConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        Contact c = value as Contact;

        try
        {
            return GetImage(c).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return @"Images/default.jpg";
    }

    async Task<BitmapImage> GetImage(Contact con)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 100;
        using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await con.Thumbnail.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
        }
        return bitmapImage;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Additional Information**
The app is set for Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT.
To get the contacts, I use a ContactStore.

```
IReadOnlyList<Contact> contacts; //Global Declaration

ContactStore store = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
contacts = await store.FindContactsAsync();
ContactsView.ItemsSource = contacts;
```

**Problem**
Every contact is returning the default contact image (meaning some exception occurred when trying to get the contact image). This shouldn’t occur since majority of my contacts have images associated with them.

**Question**
How should I get the image of a contact and bind that to an image control within a ListView for Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Are you able to retrive a single image and just set it as source of an image? Also don't make your code synchronous - better read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx), also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26150727/2681948) may help a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Romasz and Murven, I was able to get a solution for my problem.

*XAML:*

```
<ListView x:Name="ContactsView" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image x:Name="ContactImage" DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ContactPictureConverter}}" Source="{Binding Result}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

*Converter:*

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;

public class ContactPictureConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            Contact c = value as Contact;
            return NotifyTaskCompletion.Create<BitmapImage>(GetImage(c));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private async Task<BitmapImage> GetImage(Contact con)
    {
        using (var stream = await con.Thumbnail.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.DecodePixelHeight = 100;
            image.DecodePixelWidth = 100;

            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*Packages:*
[Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) from Nuget

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static BitmapImage GetImage(Contact con)
    {
        if (con == null || con.Thumbnail == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelHeight = 256;
        bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 256;


        Action load = async () =>
        {
            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await con.Thumbnail.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
            }
        };

        load();

        return bitmapImage;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the GetImage method is asynchronous, so you need to wait for the result to complete:

```
        Task<BitmapImage> getImageTask = GetImage(c);
        getImageTask.RunSynchronously();
        return getImageTask.Result;
```

Comment: I received a System.InvalidOperationException.
'RunSynchronously may not be called on a task not bound to a delegate, such as the task returned from an asynchronous method.'

Comment: Try using .Wait() instead of.RunSynchronously(). I will try to reproduce the issue when I am in front of the computer again.

Answer (score -1):

you can do one thing ..

you can retrieve all the images from the contacts class and  store them in an array or stack or List  of BitmapImages ..  (*** i think list would be an better option )

`Contact c = value as Contact;
foreach(var p in c)
{
q.Add(p.Thumbnail);
}`

here `q` is an `list of bitmapmages`