# using Microsoft.Phone workspace could not be resolved

Tags: c#, silverlight, namespaces, windows-phone-8.1

I have VS 8.1 and I'm trying to create an phone application, in which I would fetch the contacts of the phone and display them in a list.
I read about it, and assumed I have to use the Microsoft.Phone.Contact but It's not recognizes the 'Phone' in 'Microsoft'.
I've tried also to open a silverLight Application project, but it's still not recognized.
Do I have to download some extensions or libraries to use it?
thanks

Comment: try creating WP8 project (not WP8.1)

Comment: I tried also WP 8.1 app project, but it wasn't recognized also

Comment: I have to use 8.1.. Is there a way with it? May be not by using this workspace?

Comment: WP8.1 and WP8 are very different animals. the tutorial you used most likely targets WP7 or WP8.

Comment: So do you know a way to get the contacts in 8.1?

Comment: I sew there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.userdata.contacts.aspx that it should be supported in silverLight8.1

Comment: Better check if you created WP8.1 Silverlight ot Runtime app. Have you tried [to search SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows-phone-8.1%5D+get+contacts)? There are at least few questions/answers which should help you resolve the issue - [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340256/wp8-1-c-sharp-binding-contact-image).

Answer (score 0):

For WP8.1 contact binding read this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642083(v=vs.105).aspx