# WP8.1 C# Binding Contact Image, Binding Error with Nito.AsyncEx

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1, contacts

My Question is exactly as [Binding Contact Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340256/wp8-1-c-sharp-binding-contact-image/27350886#27350886)

I have followed all the steps in this, But it is resulting in the following:

```
<Image x:Name="ContactImage" DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ContactPictureConverter}}" Source="{Binding Result}" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
```

As per my understanding I have assumed Result as `Contact object` and I am providing it. But I am facing error as follows:

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'MyContact' property not found on
>   'Nito.AsyncEx.NotifyTaskCompletion+NotifyTaskCompletionImplementation

I am trying this since 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Thank Goodness, After a long debugging session and help from msdn. I got the solution

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ee9f7a1-cebc-49cb-9df5-75728e51183f/contact-picker-not-bringing-through-thumbnail?forum=winappswithcsharp