# Store image in StorageFile using IValueConverter in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, ivalueconverter

In Windows phone 8.1, I have a listview to populate the images using some collections value, I have a image in that ItemsTemplate to display the list of images,

how to store a image in StorageFile, first time i need to display image using direct server uri and after that retrieve from local storage using IValueConverter, in this I am unable to call the async method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a chance that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26150727/2681948) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Romasz, but my need is how to store that image in windows phone StorageFile,

Comment: Download the file from web and store locally, then in db you can store your local path. Or you can store base64 in database.

Comment: This could be fine, can you please share the code that could be more help full.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your requirements can be covered by caching mechanism that [Q42](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT) library implements. The library is open source so you can easily investigate the code or just reference the library in your project. Pay attention to `WebDataCache` from `Data` namespace and `ImageExtensions` from `Controls` namespace classes for implementation and `ImageCacheExamplePage`  for an example

Comment: Thanks a lot, This would be work fine for silverlight based windows phone, how to do it for Winrt Windows phone 8.1

Comment: This should definitely work for WinRT. I say it based on my own experience. And according to the description of the library - _Open source library for Universal Apps, Windows Phone and Windows 8 C#/XAML applications. This library was originally developed for Windows 8 and is fully compatible with Universal Apps (Windows Phone and Windows 8.1)._ Have a look at [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Q42.WinRT) that you can add to your project and have caching mechanism ready of the box.