# Check if Url contains Image UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a series of images stored online which I try to reach programmatically in my Universal Windows Phone App.
Is there a way to find out if the Image exists for the selected parameter and, if not, use an Image placeholder instead?

```
var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("url?ID_IMMAGINE=" + idImg1 + "&HEIGHT=100", UriKind.Absolute))
```

this is how I get the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attach a handler for the `ImageFailed` event to set a fallback value for the URI:

```
var defaultImageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/DefaultImage.png");
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.ImageFailed += (s, e) => bitmap.UriSource = defaultImageUri;
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(...);
```

Comment: When I try to use this I get the following exception:

the application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (exception from hresult: 0x8001010e (rpc_e_wrong_thread)) ... Do you know how I can fix this? The exception is thrown when I'm trying to create a new instance of BitmapImage()

Comment: @Zure Better ask a regular StackOverflow question instead of asking in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use async for Converter. return type of async method must be `void,Task,Task<T>`. That cant be given to Convert method

```
           try
            {
                var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("url?ID_IMMAGINE=" + idImg1 + "&HEIGHT=100", UriKind.Absolute));
                if (img == null)
                {
                    img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("defaultImage.png",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("defaultImage.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            }
```

If you really want to use converter please go through this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096318/wp-8-1-binding-image-from-a-http-request)

Comment: Except that `new BitmapImage(...)` neither returns null nor throws an exception when the image can't be downloaded.

Comment: If the given URL doesnt exist it throws the exception.

Comment: No it doesn't. Just give it a try.

Comment: And your code won't compile because you have declared `img` inside the try block but also access it in the catch block.

Comment: Yes i agree. should have written outside. I dint run the code and see. According to the documentation if the file name specified in uriString is not valid it throws UriFormatException. Again i dint run the sample and checked

Comment: UriFormatException is throw when the URI isn't properly formatted. The question is not about that, but about a valid URI pointing to a non-existing resource.