# UWP BitmapImage.Source - Network Uri works but Local Disk Uri does not work

Tags: uwp, uri, uwp-xaml, bitmapimage

I am setting the ImageSource of the ImageBrush of the Background to pictures in a slideshow.

Here is my property in the ViewModel

```
private ImageSource _CurrentPicture;
public ImageSource CurrentPicture { get { return _CurrentPicture; } set { Set(ref _CurrentPicture, value); } }
```

Here is the XAML

```
<ImageBrush  Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentPicture, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

When I set the Uri as the ImageSource to a file on one of my local network Servers (TpsNas) it works and displays the picture.

```
Uri uriAddress = new Uri("file://TpsNas/Photo/Trees.jpg");
CurrentPicture = new BitmapImage(uriAddress);
```

When I set the Uri to the ImageSource to a localFile on the D: drive it does not work

```
Uri uriAddress = new Uri("file:D:\\Trees.jpg");
CurrentPicture = new BitmapImage(uriAddress);
```

What is the difference?

Comment: UWP doesn't directly give access to file stored in local drives that might be the case here,(I am not sure) So usually I use FilePicker to grant permission

Comment: Aravind, I am using Win IOT, so the filepicker does not show, or I have not gotten it to show.

Comment: I guess in IOT you are limited to the sandbox folders try putting file in installation folder.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions this might help

Comment: Oh, believe me, I have been all over the docs.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: How is this question different from your other one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496950/cant-display-image-from-removeable-sd-uwp-windows-iot/54499038 

The answer is the same: UWP doesn't have a implicit value converted for file paths to ImageSource, so you will have to do it in code (or in a custom IValueConverter).

Comment: After you successfully helped me access photos on the SD card of my device, I am attempting to access the photos on my network storage device.  I can access on the NAS from my App while in Dev mode in VS,but when the app gets deployed to the device, I can't.  I guess I am having authentication issues.  Can't seem to find a way to pass credentials.  I guess I need an account  on the device that has the same credential as an account on the NAS?  Now that I discuss it, my question is not the correct question.